# Find the integer x: $x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod {210}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the integer x: $x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod {210}$

I broke the top into prime mods:

$$x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod 3$$

$$x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod {70}$$

But $x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod {70}$ can be broken up more:

$$x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod 7$$

$$x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod {10}$$

But $x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod {10}$ can be broken up more:

$$x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod 5$$

$$x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod 2$$

**In the end,I am left with:**

$$x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod 5$$

$$x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod 2$$

$$x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod 7$$

$$x \equiv 8^{38} \pmod 3$$

**Solving each using fermat's theorem:**

1. $x \equiv 8^{38}\equiv8^{4(9)}8^2\equiv64 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$
2. $x \equiv 8^{38} \equiv 8^{1(38)}\equiv 1 \pmod 2$
3. $x \equiv 8^{38} \equiv 8^{6(6)}8^2\equiv 64 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$
4. $x \equiv 8^{38} \equiv 8^{2(19)}\equiv 1 \pmod 3$

So now, I have four congruences. How can i solve them?

Comment: It's hard to see how $8^{38}\equiv 1\pmod {2}$ since $8^{38}$ is even.

Comment: The rest is chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: One last quibble - there is not one integer $x$ with this property. Indeed, you probably want the least non-negative $x$ with this property. The integer $x=8^{38}$ has this property, but that is obviously not what you are looking for.

Comment: @Thomas Oh alright, as for the $\pmod 2$ section, I used fermat's theorem where if $p$ is prime then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ but i get your reasoning so where did I go wrong?

Comment: Fermat only works if $p$ does not divide $a$. And please use `equiv 1\pmod 2`. It looks much better than $\equiv 1(\mod 2)$ - the spacing is all wrong there. Compare to this: $\equiv 1\pmod 2$.

Comment: @Thomas I see! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't know whether it will be helpful - $8^5=210\cdot{156}+8$, so $8^5\equiv8\pmod{210}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a small slip up when working $\bmod 2$, this is because $0^n$ is always congruent to $0$ no matter what congruence you are working with . I repeat this step once again.

$8^{38}\equiv 3^{38}\equiv3^{9\cdot4}3^{2}\equiv(3^{4})^{9}3^2\equiv1^9\cdot3^2\equiv9\equiv 4\bmod 5$

$8^{38}\equiv0 \bmod 2$ since it is clearly even.

$8^{38}\equiv(1)^{38}\equiv 1\bmod 7$

$8^{38}\equiv(-1)^{38}\equiv 1 \bmod 3$

So you have the following system of equations:

$x\equiv4 \bmod 5$

$x\equiv 0 \bmod 2$

$x\equiv 1 \bmod 7$

$x\equiv 1 \bmod 3$

There are general ways to solve this, but it is possible to solve it step by step using basic substitutions.

We start by writing $x=2k$ since $x\equiv 0 \bmod 2$

We now have $2k\equiv 1 \bmod 3$. Multiplying by two we get $4k\equiv 2\bmod 3$ since $4\equiv 1$ we have $k\equiv 2 \bmod 3$ so $k=3j+2$ and so $x=2(3j+2)=6j+4$

We have $6j+4\equiv 1 \bmod 7$ so $6j\equiv-3\equiv 4 \bmod 7$. Multiplying by $6$ we get $36j\equiv 24\equiv 3 \bmod 7$ Since $36\equiv 1 \bmod 7$ we have $j\equiv 3 \bmod 7$. So $x=6(7l+3)+4=42l+22$

We have $42l+22\equiv 4 \bmod 5$ from here $42l\equiv -18\equiv2 \bmod 5$ Since $42\equiv 2 \bmod 5$ we have $2l\equiv 2 \bmod 5$ so $l\equiv 1 \bmod 5$. So $l=5s+1$ and $x=42(5s+1)+22=210s+64$. So $8^{38}\equiv 64\bmod 210$

---

Second solution: Instead of using Fermat's theorem use [Carmichael's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) which says that if $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime then $a^{\lambda(n)}\equiv 1 \bmod n$. Using this and the fact that $\lambda(105)=12$

we get $8^{38}\equiv 8^{36}a^2\equiv (8^{12})^8a^2\equiv 1^38^2\equiv 8^2\equiv64\bmod 105$

Using this and the fact that $8^{38}$ is even we get $8^{38}\equiv 64\bmod 210$

---

Note: The theorem that tells us that we can separate congruences into congruences mod the power of primes dividing the number is called the Chinese Remainder theorem. This method assures us that the solution exists and that it is unique.

Comment: "It's better to use..." exactly what the OP used?

Comment: But the OP used $a^p\equiv a \bmod p$. The other format is better for the reduction.

Comment: No. Why do you think, modulo $5$, OP wrote $8^{38} = 8^{4\cdot 9}\cdot 8^2$? The same for modulo $7$ and modulo $3$. OP got modulo $2$ wrong.

Comment: Oh I see, I got confused, thank you.

Comment: @Gamamal, I did it with the chinese remainder theorem and I got it but thanks for all the alternate methods too! As for $x \equiv 4 \pmod 7$ I think you meant $x \equiv 4 \pmod 5$. Right below where you said: "So you have the following system of equations"

Comment: Wait a minute, how can you have $x \equiv 4  \pmod {7}$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod {7}$. That's a contradiction no?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in that line. It should say $x\equiv 4 \bmod 5$

Answer (score 5):

The quick solution to the Chinese Remainder Theorem exercise is to find integers $w,x,y,z$ such that $105w + 70x+42y + 30z=1$. Then:

$$x\equiv 0\cdot 105w + 1\cdot 70x + 4\cdot 42y + 1\cdot 30z\pmod {210}$$

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Somebody downvoted almost all the answers.  Just one of those questions, I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 5):

By Fermat: $\,\color{#0a0}{2,4,6}\mid\color{#c00}{12}\,\Rightarrow {\rm mod}\ \color{#0a0}{3,5,7}\!:\ 8^{\color{#c00}{12}}\equiv 1,\,$ so $\, 8^{38}\equiv 8^2(8^{\color{#c00}{12}})^3\equiv 8^2\,$ *and* $ $ mod $\,2$

---

**Remark** $\ $ It generalizes. Above is special case $\,\varphi = 36,\,k=2\,$ of the following generalization of Fermat and [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\rm\color{blue}{(E)},\,$ which clearly extends to any number of primes.

**Theorem** $\ \ \, n^{\large \varphi+k}\equiv n^{\large k}\pmod{p^i q^j}\ \ $ if $\ p\ne q\,$ are prime, $ \ \color{#0a0}{\varphi(p^i),\varphi(q^j)\mid \varphi},\ $  $\, i,j \le k $

${\bf Proof}\,\ \ p\nmid n\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod\ }p^i\!:\  n^{ \varphi}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, n^{\varphi+k}\equiv n^k,\ $ by $\,\  n^{\large \color{#0a0}\varphi} = (n^{\color{#0a0}{\large \varphi(p^{ i})}})^{\large \color{#0a0}\ell}\overset{\color{blue}{\rm (E)}}\equiv 1^{\large \ell}\equiv 1$

$\qquad\quad\ \ \color{#c00}{p\mid n}\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod\ }p^i\!:\  n^k\equiv 0\,\equiv\, n^{\varphi+k}\ $ by $\ n^k = n^{k-i} \color{#c00}n^i = n^{k-i} (\color{#c00}{mp})^i$ and $\,k\ge i$

So $\ p^i\!\mid n^{\varphi+k}\!-n^k.\,$ By symmetry $\,q^j$ divides it too, so their lcm $ = p^iq^j\,$ divides it too. $\ $ **QED**

See also [Carmichael's Lambda function,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) a generalization of [Euler's phi function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Comment: Nice,clear and concise. This is the idea behind Carmichael lambda is it not?

Comment: @Gamamal Yes, see the Remark. I planned to mention that but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for, so hopefully the above will do. Kudos to you for mentioning Carmichael too. Perhaps it should have been a separate answer since it is so easy to miss (as I did on first glance) buried at the end of your long answer.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate solution using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

First off, $2, 3, 5$ and 7 are pairwise relatively prime thus we know the following system of congruences has a unique solution modulo $2\times3\times5\times7=210$.

\begin{cases} x \equiv 4  \pmod {5} \\  x \equiv 0  \pmod {2} \\  x \equiv 1  \pmod {7} \\  x \equiv 1  \pmod {3} \end{cases}

**Start with the first congruence and turn it into an equation**

$x\equiv 4 \pmod 5$
$\iff x = 5k + 4$ (by definition of congruence)

**Plugging this in the second congruence:**

$5k+4 \equiv 0\pmod {2}$
$\iff$
$5k \equiv 0 \pmod {2}$

To get rid of the 5 on the left hand side, multiply both sides of the congruence by the inverse of 5 mod 2 which is 1 by the extended euclidean algorithm. Thus:

$k \equiv 0 \pmod {2}$
$\iff$
$k = 2k'$

Which means $x = 5k + 4 = 5(2k') + 4 = 10k' + 4$

**Now replacing in the third equation:**

$10k' + 4 \equiv 1 \pmod {7}$
$\iff$
$10k' \equiv 4 \pmod {7}$

Multiply both sides by 5, the inverse of 10 mod 7.

$k' \equiv 6 \pmod {7}$
$\iff$
$k' = 7k'' + 6$

Which means $x = 10k' +4 = 10(7k'' + 6) + 4 = 70k'' + 64$

**Finally replacing in the last equation:**

$70k'' + 64 \equiv 1 \pmod {3}$
$\iff$
$70k' \equiv 0 \pmod {3}$

Multiply both sides by 1, the inverse of 70 mod 3.

$k' \equiv 0 \pmod {3}$
$\iff$
$k'' = 3k'''$

**Thus**

$x = 70k'' + 64 = 70(3k''') + 64 = 210k''' + 64$
$\iff$
$x \equiv 64 \pmod {210}$

Comment: Generally, use `\pmod {10}` rather than `(mod 10)`, which formats horribly. Compare: $x\equiv 1\pmod{10}$ and $x\equiv 1(mod 10)$.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that does not make use of *Fermat's Little Theorem*.

---

**The Algorithm:**

- Input: $x=8,e=38,n=210$
- Output: $y=1$
- Repeat until $e=0$:

  - If $e\equiv1\pmod2$ then set $y=yx\bmod{n}$
  - Set $x=x^2\bmod{n}$
  - Set $e=\left\lfloor\frac{e}{2}\right\rfloor$

**C Implementation:**

```
int PowMod(int x,int e,int n)
{
    int y = 1;
    while (e > 0)
    {
        if (e & 1)
            y = (y*x)%n;
        x = (x*x)%n;
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return y;
}

int result = PowMod(8,38,210); // 64
```

**Intermediate Output:**

```
   x   |   e   |   y
-------|-------|-------
    8  |   38  |    1
   64  |   19  |    1
  106  |    9  |   64
  106  |    4  |   64
  106  |    2  |   64
  106  |    1  |   64
  106  |    0  |   64
```

---

Please note that the complexity is $O(\log_2e)$, resulting in $\lceil\log_238\rceil=6$ iterations.

Answer (score 2):

just apply Chinese remainder theorem (See Burton)

Answer (score 2):

Notice

$$8^5=210\cdot{156}+8$$

So

$$8^5\equiv8\pmod{210}--(1)$$

Also
$$8^2\equiv64\pmod{210}--(2)$$

By (1),(2) we have

$$8^7\equiv8\cdot{64}\equiv92\pmod{210}$$

Futhermore

$$8^{35}=(8^5)^7\equiv8^7\equiv92\pmod{210}--(3)$$

Morever

$$8^3\equiv512\equiv92\pmod{210}--(4)$$

Therefore, by (3),(4),

$$8^{38}=8^{35}\cdot8^3\equiv92^2\equiv64\pmod{210}$$

Comment: This is nice. You noticed the order of $8\bmod 105$ is $5$. This technique can sometimes be bad however, this is because if the order is large you will have arrived nowhere. It is safer to use results such as charmicael's lambda and pay the price later having to do a little longer Right-to-left binary method exponentiation.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$64\equiv 8^{38}\mod 210$$

Comment: How did you get that?